# Restful triggering of Camunda process definitions from nodejs

Tags: events, restful-architecture, bpmn, camunda

I’m a beginner at Camunda/BPMN and I want to use it to control what is going on in nodejs, mostly likely using a REST API, at least for now. (Unless folks have a better idea for how nodejs should talk to Camunda.) My goal is to deliver systems where non-programmers can update the business logic in very practical ways.

I'd like to trigger the start of perhaps more-than-one process by sending a REST message, say to reflect that "a new insurance policy has been sold" and that might trigger the instantiation of say 2 processes on Monday but perhaps on Tuesday we add a third and now the same REST API call should now trigger more activity on Wednesday. (I figure it is better for nodejs to know about events but not about the process definitions. After all, my goal is to use Camunda as a sort of business logic server for my application. The less the nodejs code needs to know, the better.)

- Which REST API should I be using to express the message that, say "a new insurance policy has been sold"? When I look at:

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/develop/reference/rest/signal/post-signal/

I find it very confusing. What should "name" match in the biz process definitions? I assume I don't need an executionId? I assume I can leave out tenantId?

- Would some string in the message match the ID of a start event in one or more process definitions (or what has to match what)?
- When I look at a process, is there an easy way to tell what variables I need to supply to start that process running?
- Should I perhaps avoid using this event-oriented style of kicking off processes and just use the POST /process-definition/key/{key}/start? It would seem to me to be better form to trigger activity with events or signals or something like that rather than to have my nodejs code know about the specific process definition by name.
- Should I be using events or signals in this case?
- I gather that the start event should not be a "None Start Event" but I'm not clear on what type of start event TO use if I want automatic triggering based on events or signals or something? Would a "Non-interrupting - Message Start Event" be the right sort? I'm finding this confusing.
- Once I have triggered the process to start, what does nodejs need to send to step the process forward from one task in that instance to the next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to instantiate a new workflow instance you have the following possibilities:

**Start exactly one instance:**

- Start a workflow instance by its known "key": https://docs.camunda.org/manual/develop/reference/rest/process-definition/post-start-process-instance/
- Start a workflow by a message start event: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/develop/reference/rest/message/post-message/. A message can only start one specific workflow instance, it is not allowed that this is not a unique relationship. The message start event is the one you have to use in your BPMN process model. See also https://docs.camunda.org/manual/develop/reference/bpmn20/events/message-events/. This might indeed be the better approach to make your client independent of the process definition key.

**Start multiple instances:**
- Start a workflow instance by a BPMN signal event: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/develop/reference/rest/signal/post-signal/. The signal name could start many instances as once.

The name of the message or name of signal would be configured in the BPMN model. Both could work for your use case.

Once a process instance is started it will move automatically execute the next steps. 
Probably following this example (https://blog.bernd-ruecker.com/use-camunda-without-touching-java-and-get-an-easy-to-use-rest-based-orchestration-and-workflow-7bdf25ac198e) step by step can give you some better idea?